# Web Accessibility - Ensure alternative text is informative for image links (SVG Images)

Tags: image, svg, alt

I'm trying to make an image link web accessible, but the image is SVG. It must be compliant with the AMP tool (found here: https://www.webaccessibility.com/express.php). The specific issue that is being thrown can be found here:

https://www.webaccessibility.com/best_practices.php?best_practice_id=370

This code snippet will pass the AMP tool perfectly..

```
 <svg role="img" class="icon icon-large">
 <title>Build a Long-Term Plan</title>
 <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-calendar"></use>
 </svg>
```

However, when it comes to wrapping that in an A tag, AMP throws an error. Here's an example of what seemingly SHOULD be OK:

```
<a href="/some-url-here/" class="some-class">
 <svg role="img" class="icon icon-large">
 <title>Build a Long-Term Plan</title>
 <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-calendar"></use>
 </svg>
 <span>Build a Long-Term Plan</span>
</a>
```

..but unfortunately, that last code snippet throws an error. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution wasn't fun, but it did the trick. You can simply take the SVG tag and all it's content out of the A tag, and then use CSS to position it where it belongs, and it will pass the tool.. I wish there was a better way but I haven't found one. If you do know something I don't, please share it, it will be much welcomed. Thanks!

Final result that works:

```
<svg role="img" class="icon icon-large">
<title>Build a Long-Term Plan</title>
<use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-calendar"></use>
</svg>
<a href="/some-url-here/" class="some-class">
 <span>Build a Long-Term Plan</span>
</a>
```